# Share internet from connected wifi like Connectify

Tags: xubuntu

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R1Dq.png)

Can i share Wifi like Connectify in ap mode?
XUbuntu 14.04

Comment: Goto network in system settings and then click on use as hotspot

Comment: It can`t share like Conecctify

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wifi router then I think you cant share the internet using hotspot ,I mean, using hostapd, hostapd may give result on cable or any external adapter.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)